# Помогите написать ругулярку "все буквы русского алфавита, за исключением группы букв "от"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Скажем, есть строка **абвгдеотто**. Должно быть 2 совпадения: **абвгде** и **то**, **от** сматчиться не должен. Я думал, что должен сработать **[А-Яа-я[^(от)]]=**, но почему-то нет. Я проверяю на regex101, синтаксис JS.

Comment: Непонятно, почему ты думал, что так должно сработать. И там справа пояснение что делает кажый фрагмент выражения. Часть ``[^(от)`` ищет любой символ из указанных.

Comment: А вообще какая задача? А то может без регулярок можно намного проще сделать

Comment: @Эникейщик, я могу без регулярок решить да. Но мне бы хотелось понять, как с ними такое можно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете, как обычно в таких случаях, найти то, что вам не нужно, и найти и захватить то, что вам нужно.

```js
const results = 'абвгдеотто'.matchAll(/от|((?:(?!от)[А-ЯЁа-яё])+)/g)
console.log( Array.from(results, x => x[1]).filter(y => y !== undefined) )
```

Здесь `от|((?:(?!от)[А-ЯЁа-яё])+)` находит `от` или одну и более букв, которая не является начальной буквой подстроки `от` (захватывая данную последовательность в подмаску №1).

`Array.from(results, x => x[1]).filter(y => y !== undefined)` оставляет только те значения, которые были захвачены.